# Using ServiceLoader for log4j-jcl brigde in OSGi environment

Tags: osgi, log4j2, apache-commons-logging

I am trying to use the log4j-jcl bridge in osgi mode and found that the java.util.ServiceLoader should be used to get the LogFactoryImpl from the bridge jar. I am new to OSGi and so tried it after referring to a few tutorials but it doesn't seem to work. The bundle is in RESOLVED state.

LoggingActivator.java

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import java.util.ServiceLoader;

public class LoggingActivator  implements BundleActivator{

private static Log log;
ServiceLoader<LogFactory> serviceLoader = ServiceLoader.load(LogFactory.class);
LogFactory service = serviceLoader.iterator().next();

public LoggingActivator(){
    if (service != null){
        log = service.getLog(LoggingActivator.class);
    }
}

@Override
public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
    log.info("Activated Logging");
}

@Override
public void stop(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
    log.info("Deactivated Logging");
}


}
```

pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

---

```
    <Export-Package>
        org.apache.logging.log4j.*,
        org.apache.commons.logging.*
    </Export-Package>
    <Import-Package>
        !org.apache.logging.log4j.*,
        !org.apache.commons.logging.*,
        *;resolution:=optional
    </Import-Package>
```

Answer (score 0):

The ServiceLoader does not work well in OSGi. I propose to give [Apache Karaf](http://karaf.apache.org) a try. You will not need it later but it has the logging already configured properly so it is easier to start with compared to setting all up yourself from the start.

In your bundle simply initialize a commons logging logger like outside of OSGi.

```
class MyClass {
private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(MyClass.class);
...
}
```

Leave the maven-bundle-plugin at defaults. The result is a bundle that imports the commons logging API packages which is exactly what you need.

Then start karaf and deploy your bundle. The logging should work out of the  box. For more information see the [karaf logging guide](https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/#_log).

Karaf uses pax-logging. If you want to setup this yourself you need the bundles pax-logging-api and pax-logging-service, felix config admin and felix fileinstall. The backend is log4j. You configure it using ConfigAdmin and a config named etc/org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg. The config is a standard log4j config file.

Comment: Is it a good idea to make another server up and running just to enable logging? I doubt it would affect the startup time of the main server.

Comment: This is not what I mean. Simply create a simple bundle to demonstrate logging like I suggested and deploy it in karaf to test it. Then recreate the pax-logging setup in your real setup. After this step you do not need karaf anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make use of ServiceLoader then you should probably take a look at the Service Loader Mediator specification (chapter 133 of the OSGi compendium). There is an implementation called SPI Fly hosted at Apache Aries.

The idea is that the Service Loader mediator extends your bundle's classes at runtime, making sure that it has the Thread Context ClassLoader set correctly for your uses of `ServiceLoader` to find implementations. The Service Loader Mediator also registers OSGi services for each registered implementation that it finds, so you can avoid using `ServiceLoader` completely by using the OSGi service registry if you choose.